# PGError: SSL connection failure, H10 error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku

My application using heroku and postgresql is 100% down and the application crashes with an `H10 error`. I believe the log below is the route of the problem:

```
2012-08-28T19:17:44+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1194:in `initialize': FATAL:  role "arseiiyfkbqalv" is not permitted to log in (PGError)
```

Comment: was it ever up? is there also user with that role? try connecting with the user and not the role.

Comment: yes, the application was working just fine earlier in the day.

Comment: were there any changes to the code?

Comment: i changed the posgresql database size to the basic plan on heroku to allow for more rows, as we had reached the limit for the dev plan.

Comment: interesting. i'd contact heroku support and ensure that everything was completely transitioned.

Comment: do you connect with a password?

Comment: Got it all fixed, the error was due to my heroku databases that had were not provisioned. i had to reset my database and then restore it from a back up.

Comment: This just happened to me today. I didn't change anything...

Answer (score 7):

(I just your case as I work at the heroku data team)

You deprovisioned your dev database, but have not updated your dyno's configuration to make it connect to a new one. You can do that by running `heroku pg:promote HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_<NEW COLOR> --app your-app`

You can view a list of databases currently on your app by running `heroku pg:info --app your-app`. The database that is promoted as the primary will also show that it is `DATABASE_URL`.

Comment: Thats an excellent answer, would be great if you could show this simple command as a note once I remove my old database after ordering a new one (with only one remaining). Anyway, problem solved.